# How to set object value as key to other value of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

current data

```
[ 
  {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "Active",
    "value": "Y",
    z"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "controls",
    "value": "N",  
  }
]
```

result data

```
  {"Active":"Y",
  "controls":"N"}
```

how to map value of one item in object as another item key ( as one object)

Comment: is it `"value": "Y, Z"`?

Comment: `yourarray.map(({name,value}) => ({[name]:value}))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
x = [{
    "id": 0,
    "name": "Active",
    "value": "Y",
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "controls",
    "value": "N",
  }
]

a = x.reduce((a, b) => ({...a,  [b.name]: b.value }), {})

console.log(a)

s = x.map(item => ({ [item.name]: item.value }))

console.log(s)
```

Comment: the answer should be like { Active:"Y","Controls:"N} as one object

Comment: @shashank please check now

Comment: Thanks Jay, can we do this like if its Y then true , if N then false and if value =123 then just 123

Comment: Yes you can put conditions at [b.name]: b.value

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [ 
{ "id": 0, "name": "Active", "value": "Y" }, 
{ "id": 1, "name": "controls", "value": "N" },
]


const result = data.map(item => {
  return {
    [item.name]: item.value
  }
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: the answer should be like { Active:"Y","Controls:"N} as one object

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```js
let elements = [ { "id": 0, "name": "Active", "value": "Y"}, 
    { "id": 1, "name": "controls", "value": "N"},
] 


let new_element = Object()

elements.forEach(element=>{     
    new_element[element.name] = element.value
})
console.log(new_element)
```